# How to stop ios mail converting times into links

Tags: ios, email, calendar

If iOS mail receives an email with some text similar to `09:45 - 10:15`, it will convert it into a link to add an event to the calendar, for **today**.

How can this behaviour be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ratio](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2236/index.htm) entity instead of a normal colon.

So, instead of `09:45 - 10:15`, you would use `09&#8758;45 - 10&#8758;15`.